# how to debug sqlite with not a amalgamation source code?

Tags: c++, c, database, sqlite, clion

I am student in database group at my college.

I am analysize sqlite3 source code recently! I try to use amalgamation sourcecode (yes it's size over 7.8M). this file is so big that I can't debug into it.such as watch some varibles or some expression. My environment of code is ubuntu 16.04 Clion 2016.2.3.

- I tried to use Eclipse for c/c++ ,that can debug amalgmation source code, but very slow, and I am not familiar using Eclipse
- I try to read some rules to wite makefile and cmakefile, but I don't know how to solve the source code dependence
- I try to make Clion memory bigger in config file,that can use nice feature in clion, but my CPU will run 100% every time I modify my source code
- I also try to learn some tcl script, I find the script to amalgmate the all small file to one big sqlite.c .

I want to find solution to run sqlite source code with not amalgamation code.

[image: so big that some nice features can't use in clion]

[image: tcl to amalgamate source code to big one]

[image: my cmake file use amalgamation source code]

[image: my computer is power with SSD]

Comment: this is my screen shot in my question above. the stackoverflow require 10 reputation to upload image~ but i am freshman in stackoverflow   /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Answer (score -1):

debugging the amalgamation code does not seem to be a good choice. I also would rather use the raw source of SQLite and when everything works fine, follow the steps to build the amalgamation yourself (Chapter 4 of the [howto compile](https://sqlite.org/howtocompile.html)).

To use the raw sources, go to the bottom of the [Download page of SQlite](https://sqlite.org/download.html). There you will find the [alternative sources](https://sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-src-3160200.zip). Download them and do the usual three steps (configure && make && sudo make install) to install the lib to your system or skip the latter and link to your sqlite compile path in your project.

Good Luck!

Comment: I did the three steps , and install the lib and could run my project,but i can't debug this.also can't step into the source file.  did you met the same situation?

Comment: How die you try to debug? Which IDE, Debugger,... With only little Information, it is hard to help out.